# Performance of Solr Shared is worse than Solr Unsharded

Tags: solr, full-text-search, tomcat7, cluster-computing, sharding

I have been tasked with building a test index of about 100million small records using Solr. I have been running this on my laptop since some time yesterday, incrementing it by 10million records at a time and running queries at the major "milestones" (10m, 20m... etc). I have reached about 70million records, and all is going well... The laptop specs are as follows:

- Quad Core i7
- 8Gb RAM
- Windows 7
- Tomcat 7 + latest version of Solr.

As a test, I decided to see what happens when i run a simular workload on my home workstation (Dual Proc, Quad Core Xeon, 12Gb RAM, 2x10K RPM Disks in RAID 0 for index, Windows 2008 R2, same software). Only difference is now i am using Multi Cores... using the same schema and conf directory from the laptop, modified the solr.xml...

Anyway, on the laptop, at about 70 million records, i am getting results of less than 500ms. thats 150 queries, 100 of which are one word, 50 are 2 word queries. only one field is queried (name field). all good... On my workstation, using multi cores and the following querystring, i am getting times in excess of 4-5 seconds!

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/core0/select?shards=localhost:8080/solr/core0,localhost:8080/solr/core1,localhost:8080/solr/core2,localhost:8080/solr/core3&q=Name:Test Name
```

This is a new Index i have generated: i am doing a loop, from 0 to 100,000,000 and every time i hit i % 10000 == 0 i add the documents to a solr core. Each time I hit that loop, I incrememt a commitID, and when commitID %4 == 0, go to core0, when 1 go to core1, etc...

I am pretty sure its a config issue somewhere... but i just want to make sure... Should I be expecting this to be a lot faster? both processors (Laptop and Workstation) are in around the 2.2Gz range. Both are new enough architectures (Nehalem on the Workstation, i7 from 2010 on the laptop). So, any ideas what i should be looking at?

Comment: Try to do the tests on the same machine. One test with multi cores and one test with a single core. I also had some problem on a work station, it was working slower then on my pc (with the same solr configuration). It turned out to be a server processor power setting problem.

Comment: i will try and and see what kind of speed i can get. the Server procs are set to use full power, as is the laptop, so i dont think its that, but i will check it out.

Comment: The queries in a multishard environment are slower as it needs to merge the results, but 4-5 seconds it's a lot compared to 0.5 in a single core.  How much time it takes to query one core in a multi shards environment? If it is under 1 second then its probably a configuration problem somewhere.

Comment: its taking a little over a second on a single core...

Comment: Let me see if I understand this:
-On local computer one core with 70mil u have a query in 0.5 seconds
-On server  one core with 17.5 mil ( 70 / 4) docs u have a query in 1 second
In this case there is a server problem.

Comment: the server actually only has about 24 million across 4 cores... I have found out my memory may not be performing as well as it should... I may have put it in the wrong slots... but even still, this should not account for such a slow speed, right? Any suggestions to making it faster, if the memory "fix" does not work?